# Can everyone answer my confusion regarding the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, types-of-sentences

Sentence: "In this study, we examine the perception English instructors have on the different degrees of grammar skills and Thai-oriented English accent". Is it simple sentence or complex sentence?

And another question. When a subordinating conjunction "That"is removed in a subordinate clause, is it still a complex sentence? Or does it become simple sentence because there's no subordinate conjunction?

Comment: Please don't ask two different questions in the same post.

Comment: Welcome to ELL, Siti.

Answer (score 1):

> *In this study, we **examine** the perception* [*English instructors **have** on*
> *the different degrees of grammar skills and Thai-oriented English*
> *accent*].

There are two verbs present so there must be two clauses, one of them (in brackets) being a subordinate clause. In some traditional grammars it would therefore be called a complex sentence.

The omission of the subordinator "that" has no effect on its status as a complex sentence.